# How can my partials access the main data object in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using Vue Router to router external .vue files and tie them together with webpack. I have a main.js object that defines my Vue instance.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  //render: h => h(App),
  data:{
    msg: 'Hello there'
  }
});
```

My partials export themselves as modules, but I want my partials to be able to access the data from the main.js, but they can only access data from their own data object.

```
export default {
  name: 'foo',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'You have no brain'
    }
  }
}
```

So from within that partial {{msg}} says You have no brain but I want it to say Hello there. How do I do that?

Comment: Use [props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props)

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to just use variables from another file. It's Vue, so you need to read how to connect [Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html). Using [Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props) can help you as well.

Keep in mind that all of this has nothing to do with how you separate your code into files. It's a whole ecosystem and you need to connect stuff in Vue, not in JS files :)

Answer (score 0):

When your app will grow and you will certainly get multiple "co-dependent" values etc. you will probably get to the point that such methods will not be very "readable".

I suggest you look into "state management" - in the example of Vue maybe Vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) as it will soon be required in medium to large size of all your apps.

Otherwise you can use "event bus" communication (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication). But you will probably "outgrow" it pretty soon...

Hope it helps...